# How to add PlaceHolders in TextFields after you clear the text

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitextfield

I have a button that clears all my textfields, but after they are cleared, I want to immediately replace the placeholders. However, my code doesn't work and the textfields remain blank after they are cleared. This is what I've tried:

```
[self clearTextFields];     
personWhoOwesYouMoney.placeholder = @"Person who owes you";
amtTheyOwe.placeholder = @"Amount Owed (USD)";
cellNum.placeholder = @"Their cell number";
```

my clearTextFields method is just a function that returns void which just sets all the textfields.text to @" "

I also tried putting the code in ViewdidLoad and that didn't work either. I have manually entered placeholders in the storyboard. All I'm trying o do is retrieve those same placeholders after I clear my textfields.

Answer (score 2):

You're setting the fields' text to `@" "` - which is a space. Instead, set them to `@""` (no space between the quotes).

Comment: Thanks, but...it doesn't exactly solve my placeholder problem.

Comment: Why is it that even in the ViewdidLoad my placeholders won't get set?

Comment: @doc92606, What do you mean by "doesn't exactly solve my placeholder problem"?

Comment: I mean when I clear all the text on my textfields, they are completely empty. I want them to be rid of text, but I still want the placeholders to stay.

Comment: So, have you tried what Graham Perks suggested, cause @" " makes them clean but not empty. Empty = no characters at all.

Comment: Yes, I did. The placeholders still don't come back.